# How to solve missing/hidden window in Geany?

Tags: windows-7, geany

I have installed Geany 0.19.1 on Windows 7, I run the Geany.exe shortcut and it appears running on my windows taskbar,  if I hit Alt+Tab I see the Geany icon. But... no window is shown. Where is the Geany window? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>, then <kbd>M</kbd>, then the arrow keys to move the window into view.

Comment: Perfect... thanks!!! ¿Qué habré hecho que perdí la ventana en primer lugar?

Comment: Not a clue. I choose to be willfully ignorant of how Windows does most things to begin with. Cuts down on the family support requests.

Comment: You probably moved it out of the working area by clicking some voodoo key combination by mistake. Dual monitors likely to be involved, that was my case.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> then <kbd>M</kbd> didn't work for me, but <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> then <kbd>x</kbd> **did**.

Comment: This worked for me, too, it maximizes the window (in a way that doesn't matter where it was in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

Having this problem, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> then <kbd>M</kbd> didn't work  for me.

However, upgrading latest GTK bundle binaries from [GTK download page](http://www.gtk.org/download/win32.php) did the trick:

- on the said page, find link "select all-in-one bundle"
- in the downloaded archive, copy dlls from bin directory bin directory of Geany

Answer (score 0):

I was solving this problem on my Raspberry Pi today at 10 o`clock in the morning.. I changed the configuration file : geany.conf - "fullscreen=false".